# Make only a cell value highlighted in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angularjs and when updating a certain value in the table I would like to add a CSS class, to only that specific cell.

- How do I only add the highlight class too only that cell? And not the whole row...Using angular directive

Expected behavior: Since Value2 is updated, only that cell should be highlighted.

My plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mfglNOpluccUKLTlLdja?p=preview

my table:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 320px;" class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
  <thead style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked" ng-bind="column.id"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">

      <td ng-repeat="column in columnsTest" ng-if="column.checked">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" ng-show="column.id === 'Value1'"></span>
        <span data-highlighter="row.Updated">{{row[column.id]}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
.highlight {
background-color: lightgreen;
transition: background 200ms;
}
```

angular directive:

```
app.directive('highlighter', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        model: '=highlighter'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('model', function(updated) {
                if (updated) {


                element.addClass('highlight');

                // auto remove after some delay
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.removeClass('highlight');
                }, 1000);
                }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "`row.Updated` gets undefined"? What makes you say that, and how is it a problem? Your plunk looks to me like it's working as it should; what's the desired behavior?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My expected behavior is that only one cell should be highlighted, and not the whole row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is the problem:

```
model: '=highlighter'
```

because

```
<span data-highlighter="row.Updated">
```

this will give `model` the value of `row.Updated`, and that is a value that will have changed on all three columns, because it is defined on their parent.

Change it to

```
<span data-highlighter="row[column.id]">
```

Then it works.

---

*Edit: removed my previous answer.*

Comment: I wanna use the directive. As you can see I also remove the css class there as well

Comment: The point is that all three cells in the row are looking at the same variable, `row.Updated`, so if one cell gets updated and sets that flag, the whole row gets highlighted. @C14L's recommendation is good: instead of watching a flag on the parent that you have to manually set yourself, why don't you just watch the value that can change directly? If you use `data-highlighter="row[column.id]"`, the directive will automatically watch for the column's value to change and will highlight just that column each time it does. No need to manually trigger it with an Updated flag

Comment: Here's a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JL691xJfPqKJ4DaacP0m?p=preview ; one thing to notice is that I changed the `$watch` callback to take 2 vars, `updated` and `previous`, and changed `if (updated)` to `if (!angular.equals(updated, previous))`. This will make sure the value has actually changed and prevents things like all the cells flashing when the page first loads because the `$watch()` always fires the first time